# What does it mean to append "\<num>" to file paths under HKCR\TypeLib\<TypeLib>

Tags: windows, registry, typelib

I've seen several (not all) registry values like the followings, when trying to parse out the file path under the TypeLib registry key:

```
HKEY_CLASS_ROOT\TypeLib\\{EE9CFA8C-F997-4221-BE2F-85A5F603218F}\1.0\0\win64(Defalt): C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\VFS\ProgramFilesX64\Microsoft Office\Office16\OCHelper.dll\1

HKEY_CLASS_ROOT\TypeLib\\{F9E34568-0298-46D3-B9C4-19AFB415CBA8}\1.0\0\win32(Default): C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Packages\mswebprj.dll\5

HKEY_CLASS_ROOT\TypeLib\\{F2A7EE29-8BF6-4a6d-83F1-098E366C709C}\1.0\0\win32(Default): C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Root\Office16\ONENOTE.EXE\2
```

Each file path is appended with a backslash followed a number. Apparently, these file paths are not legal to file system. I'm wondering if anyone recognizes the syntax, and what the appendix means to a typelib registration under these registry key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

usually we use [`LoadRegTypeLib`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221121(v=vs.85).aspx) for load typelib based on registry information. the The function `LoadRegTypeLib` defers to [`LoadTypeLib`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221027(v=vs.85).aspx) to load the file. and read *Remarks* section for [`LoadTypeLib`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221027(v=vs.85).aspx)

> By default, the type library is extracted from the first resource of
>   type *ITypeLib*. **To load a different type of library resource,
>   append an integer index to szFile**. For example:

```
ITypeLib *ptlib;
LoadTypeLib("C:\\MONTANA\\EXE\\MFA.EXE\\3", &ptlib)
```

> This statement loads the type library resource 3 from the file Mfa.exe
>   file.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio use File > Open > File and select C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Packages\mswebprj.dll.  You'll see the resources embedded in the DLL.  Open the TYPELIB node and you'll instantly see what 5 means.

It is the resource id.

More typically there is only one type library embedded in the file and has resource id #1.  Sometimes the type library is not embedded but stored in a separate file, commonly with the .tlb or .olb filename extension.  Like a .NET [ComVisible] assembly, Office is a common example.